# Подсчет количество строк из двух таблиц sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Никак не могу сообразить как осуществить `sql` запрос таким образом, чтобы подсчитать соответствующие поля в связки двух таблиц.

Имеется следующая структура таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;



CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
`tbl1_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

INDEX (`tbl1_id`),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Нужно посчитать количество всех строк первой таблицы и именно тех, которых нет во второй. Первая таблица связана со второй по следующим полям: `tbl1`.`id` и `tbl2`.`tbl1_id`
То-есть, если 20 `id`шников первой таблицы нет во второй, то результат должен быть 20.
Каким образом можно подсчитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `left join`. Соединяете таблицы, смотрите, какие строки не соединились, считаете их количество:

```
select count(t1.id)
from tbl1 t1 left join tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.tl1_id
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: *смотрите, какие поля не соединились* - вероятно, не поля, а записи?

Comment: @Akina Думаю данный ответ посчитает и повторяющиеся колонки.тут надо либо `GROUP BY t1.id` добавить , либо так `select count(DISTINCT(t1.id))`.Как вы думаете  ?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan про данные ТС ничего не говорил, если там повторы или нет. С таким успехов можно делать проверку на `null` поля `t1` и всё остальное.

Comment: @Akina да, вероятно, не поля, а записи, поправил.